# Node.js: How to create ES6 module in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, ecmascript-6, module

This is the old example of creating a Node.js addon in C++:
https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

It can be built with node-gyp to a common JS module, which works fine with function 'require'. However, the compiled module can't be imported in .mjs file.

This works fine: `node test.js`

```
// test.js
var m = require("./build/Release/addon");
console.log(m.hello());
```

This doesn't: `node --experimental-modules test.mjs`

```
// test.mjs
import * as m from "./build/Release/addon";
console.log(m.hello());
```

The error is: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module`

That C++ addon example page is for the old Node.js with common JS, any examples for C++ addon that can be built to be ES6 module to import in .mjs files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node [does not currently support loading native modules with `import` syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_native_module_loading).

In an ESM file, you will need to do:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const m = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log(m.hello());
```